# How to create a password protected database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a password protected SQLite database to use within a WPF application using Entity Framework Core.

I know how to generate DbContext and Entities from an existing database but don't know how to create a password protected database. What is the difference between an encrypted database and a password protected database?

Comment: you encrypt the DB via `dbCon.SetPassword(myLitePW)` thereafter you use the PW in the connection string: `Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Password=myLitePW;`

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this works with EF6 (within the System.Data.SQLite package). But with EF Core (within the Microsoft.Data.SQLite package), I can't find a way to do so ... (there is no SetPassword methods in the SQLiteConnection from the Microsoft.Data.SQLite)

Comment: "*What is the difference between an encrypted database and a password protected database?*" There is no password without encryption.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to this [article](http://www.bricelam.net/2016/06/13/sqlite-encryption.html) and this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/184), there is no way (yet?) to encrypt the database using the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite assembly (used by `EF Core`).

Based on this, here is what I've done to get it working with `EF Core`:

- add the [System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) package to the project
- while configuring your dbContext, give the `optionsBuilder` your own `DbConnection`:

  ```
  var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=yourSQLite.db;");
  conn.Open();

  var command = conn.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = "PRAGMA key = password;";
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(conn);
  ```

It is very important to use the `SQLiteConnection` (which can manage encrypted database) from the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` assembly and not the `SqliteConnection` from `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`.

---

According to the article, you could probably used the built in `SqliteConnection` by replacing the `sqlite3.dll` shipped within the `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` assembly by another one that handle encrypted database (you can find a free one on this [repo](https://github.com/rindeal/SQLite3-Encryption)). But I did not tested it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38368369/2183236) is how to do this !

Answer (score 1):

I was pleasantly surprised with how smooth the solution described [here](https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore) was for me.

1. Navigate to the [github repo](https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore) and scroll down to the steps.
2. Install/remove the NuGet in steps 1 to 4.
3. Modify your DbContext bit:

   ```
   public class MyDbContext: DbContext {

     public MyDbContext(): base() {}

     protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder) {
         SqliteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder();
         builder.DataSource = @"myDatabase.db";
         builder.Password = "myPassword";

         optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(new SqliteConnection(builder.ConnectionString));
     }

     //... and some other unrelated stuff ...

   }
   ```

---

**Some notes**:

- If you don't really care for the existing data, it might be easier to just delete the previous database. If you do care, you [can give it a shot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19623538/1754152).
- If you already have 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' installed, you don't need to install the 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' NuGet.